# How can I get links to stay active?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm making a site with a lecture on. The lecture is divided into chapters. Each chapter has it's own link and when clicked a new video loads an external html get loaded into a text window. I need these links to stay active, so that ppl know what chapter they're on.

Here's my current html:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadContent('#pres', chapter1.html');changeVideo('chapter1')">chapter1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadContent('#pres', 'chapter2.html');changeVideo('chapter2')">chapter2</a></li>
```

..and so on..

Now, this works perfectly.. As I said, I need the links to stay active, and tried adding an addClass(this)
I.E:

```
onclick="javascript:loadContent('#pres','chapter2.html');changeVideo('chapter2');addClass(this)">... 

function addClass(obj)
{
  obj.className="active";
}
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried removing everything but the addClass function with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also set the css of the `active` class? A class `.active` and the pseudo class `:active` are not the same.

Comment: I did, did misspell though, but it didn't help correcting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clickChapter(type, page, chapter){
    loadContent(type, page);
    changeVideo(chapter);
    removeAllClass();
    addClass(ocument.getElementById('id_'+chapter));
}

function removeAllClass(){
    var aAnchor = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i=0; i<aAnchor.length;  i++){
        aAnchor[i].className = '';
    }
}

<li><a href="#" id="id_chapter1" onclick="clickChapter('#pres', 'chapter1.html', 'chapter1')">chapter1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id_chapter2" onclick="clickChapter('#pres', 'chapter2.html', 'chapter2')">chapter2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

first create a Cascaded style sheet(CSS) and in it write the code like :

```
a:active {
    color: #006600;
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, San-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

```
a:visited {
    color: #006600;
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, San-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

```
a:link {
    color: #006600;
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, San-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

then paste this code in the head of your html page:

```
 <link type="text/css" href="<Path of the CSS>.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```